# Этимология слов "комик"

Tags: этимология, история, греческий

Ясно, что от греческого комикус.
Но в греческих словарях значение описано по смыслу - веселый и т.д.

А какова этимология? Комедия = песня Комосу.

трагос - козел

а комос - ?

1. Другое имя Диониса?
2. медведь? - как описано в странной версии тут на сайте к вопросу о скоморохах

Answer (score 1):

> А какова этимология [слова **комик**]?

(По данным этимологического словаря Черных.)
В русский попало из французского *комический, комик*. Первоначально появилось в XVIII в. в значении *автор комедии* и *актёр*. В значении *шутник, весельчак* распространилось только к концу XIX в. Первоисточник — греческое прилагательное "комикос" — "комический" и как сущ. "комик (актёр)" и "автор комедии", от греческого "комос" — *весёлое шествие, весёлая толпа*. Этимология самого слова *комос* не вполне понятна; предположительно оно связано со словом "деревня", но эта версия оспаривается.

> Комедия = песня Комосу.

Нет. Комедия — буквально "весёлое шествие (гуляние) с песнями" (этимологический словарь Шанского). В других этимологических словарях приводится подобный перевод с небольшими вариациями.

> трагос - козел
>   а комос - ?

Комос — "весёлая толпа" ("весёлое шествие").

> Другое имя Диониса?

Нет.

> медведь? - как описано в странной версии тут на сайте к вопросу о скоморохах

Нет.
(Доподлинно этимология греческого слова неизвестна, но эти странные версии нигде не упоминаются.)